# data-post-id="__" css selector?

Tags: wordpress, selector

Is it possible to hide an element via css from HTML markup "data-post-id="226""? I'm in wordpress and on the portfolio I need to hide an element on several posts, but since it's automated I can't do it manually.

I tried .data-post-226 { display:none; } since that works for page and post id's, but this is a little different since the id is in quotes.

Comment: please close this answer by marking the appropriate posts as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.classname` only works for classes, not for other attributes. You can select by attribute with square brackets, though.

`[data-post-id="226"]` will work as a selector to style the element that das data-post-id="226" as an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is attribute selector. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

If you are new to this, I would recommend you reading about various ways you can select your elements using CSS selectors - https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the attribute selector here (More info: https://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/)

In your case, this is what you need:

```
[data-post-id="226"] {
    display: none;
}
```